# Is the hard disk of a late 2015 27" iMac 5k still replaceable?

Tags: hard-drive, imac

I'm getting different information from the web vs. Gravis. I'd like to know if the HDD of a late 2015 iMac 27" model can still be replaced.

According to Gravis it's soldered.

My idea was to get a cheap HDD based model and replace the HDD with a fast/large SSD, like I did in my 2012 model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - Apple provides an internal SATA drive with standard connectors but custom firmware.

[According to iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+27-Inch+Retina+5K+Display+Hard+Drive+Replacement/30522) if you take the screen off carefully you can replace it, you may have to buy a bracket to secure it SSD that don't match the existing 2.5 inch drive mounting screws.

Looking at the steps it doesn't seem to be to complicated to do but with the 5k iMac you need to be extremely careful since you have to remove the speakers.

I would paste in the step by step images however there a load of them and you would be better off going to the site and taking a look at the images.

Also make sure you have the right screw drivers since its a t20 screw you would need a T20 * 100m screw driver.

Comment: I would say getting the adhesive off the screen and not damaging the camera and display cables are the "hard" part of this repair. Also note in the comments at iFixit that people putting in arbitrary drives without Apple specific firmware report that the fans on the iMac operate at elevated speeds with increased noise. https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+27-Inch+Retina+5K+Display+Hard+Drive+Replacement/30522

Comment: I know about this guide; it is about Late 2014 and Early 2015 models and Gravis confirms it is possible in those. Where in the *late* 2015 it no longer is.

Answer (score 0):

The late 2015 iMac with fusion drive has a standard 3.5" mechanical hard drive with custom firmware by Apple (which causes the fan issues others have noted) and a separate 128gb PCI-e ssd which provides the 'fusion' part, it is not a typical hybrid hdd with an internal ssd partition. The hdd is replaceable but unless you are replacing it with an Apple service part you will need a special cable/adapter with an inline temperature sensor so the fans don't run constantly. OWC has all the parts you would need to swap your internal mechanical drive for an ssd and very comprehensive instructions with videos. Be aware that if the drive is swapped out this may 'break' the fusion feature and you may have to do a bit of low-level work in disk utility to restore it.